# How to block all porn websites from firewall?

Tags: windows, firewalls, ubuntu

I want to block all porn websites and similar contents in my Windows 7 PC using Windows firewall. Till now I can block it by inserting sites one by one. Is there any category defined for such sites or contents so that I can block all porn sites and contents from my windows PC.

If it is possible to block all such sites and contents such as videos and Images from my PC then please tell me the method.

Please also tell me how to do the same in Ubuntu 16.04.

*I do not want to use any third party application for Windows and Ubuntu other than firewall.

Comment: If you really want to block *all* such sites, your best bet is to block everything, then whitelist the sites you deem safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really, really want to use only the firewall, your best bid is to copy/paste this [list](http://pasted.co/b2dc3032) manually in your firewall since this is your only option of blocking adult-content from Firewall!

As other may have advised, [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/), is good option regarding different packages of filtration. Note, some have reported that [openDNS](https://www.opendns.com/) does not always provide the best filtration of adult contents.

> If it is possible to block all such sites and contents such as videos and Images from my PC then please tell me the method.

Yes, but not with firewall. You either need a browser plugin or To be able to block every adult-content, videos, pictures etc...You need third-party application that have maintained databases of this type of content, it will take care of that for you automatically, 3rd-party will have responsive collection of updated database that contain all of this on regular basis done for you.

> Please also tell me how to do the same in Ubuntu 16.04.

Same follows to other OS's, you need a database of the content or domains you're trying to block, there is no easy,fast way around this with firewall only!

> *I do not want to use any third party application for Windows and Ubuntu other than firewall.

Then add this [list](http://pasted.co/b2dc3032) provided in your firewall, it is tremendous amount of domains, you can take that to the next level and start to build your own customized firewall.

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet may be to head over to OpenDNS.com and setup your network interfaces to block sites by category according to your preferences. You simply replace your current DNS ips with 208.67.220.220 and 208.67.222.222. It's a free, maintenance free solution that additionally offers some protection against the DNS attacks that we are seeing frequently today.

Also, since you are adding these IP addresses for your network interfaces, i.e., ethernet, wireless, it will work across browsers. You can even configure the block page the user sees. There are also other options including Comodo.com. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

You need to rely on someone else's judgement. If you just don't want to install 3rd party software, you can switch your DNS to OpenDNS, register an account and rely on their filtering.

Refer to [FamilyShield Parental Controls](https://blog.opendns.com/2010/06/23/introducing-familyshield-parental-controls/) for more information.

Other than that you can use Windows native parental controls, however there is some controversy about privacy, read more at [Inside Microsoft Family and Windows 10 Parental Controls](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/5187/inside-microsoft-family-and-windows-10-parental-controls).

Read also about [Parental Controls](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ParentalControls). There is a filtering package Gnome Nanny, however its blacklist does not seem to be actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

You can whitelist Ips you want to allow and only allow approved ip addresses. It's initially painful, but doesn't depend on questionably maintained blacklists. Default deny is the most effective way to secure traffic coming into or leaving your network.

Answer (score 0):

Three solutions:

1. You can get part of adult site list in here: http://www.alexa.com/topsites/category/Top/Adult
2. Install a web filtering software in your PC.
3. Using OpenDNS as your DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

Pihole is a great tool for this, but it also blocks ads and trackers. I understand you don’t want to install stuff.

Comment: This requires far more than 3rd party software, this suggestion requires a specific device. I'm not sure that this meets the requirements.